# Mobile Broadband for only one host

Tags: networkmanager, dhcp, route

What is the easiest method to configure a mobile broadband connection in a way that:

1. no default route is added
2. a route to a specific host is added

The connection is managed by Network Manager. The interface is configured via dhcp (`10.0.0.0` subnet behind a NAT gateway), either by Network Manager or manually by shell scripts.

In Network Manager one can choose an option:
"Use this connection only for resources on its network" which prevents setting of a default route.

My approach was to directly use shell scripts that invoke `dhclient`, extract the gateway ip and add a route from the shell script.
However, I could not find a way to prevent dhclient from adding routes.

So my goal is to have the following routes configured:

`10.215.214.128/28 dev wwp0s29u1u4i6 proto kernel scope link src 10.63.141.138
1.2.3.4 via 10.215.214.131 dev wwp0s29u1u4i6`

The first rule is added by Network Manager.
I can manually create the second route only if I know the gateway, in this case `10.215.214.131`, but how can I get the gateway if not from the routing table?

Edit: Maybe it is possible to exchange dhcp messages without configuring the interface, like a simulated run.

Comment: I believe that you need to answer your own question: How in the world can the computer know the IP address of the router if it’s not hard-coded (or stored in a file) and you refuse to get it via DHCP? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Would deleting the default routes *after DHCP has added them* be a good solution?  Ping me @Fabby if that's good enough, because the only other way is to go fully static.

Comment: IIRC `dhclient` has hooks that allow you to modify its behaviour (e.g. add your custom route based on the gateway IP, instead of the gateway route).